# What does 'high-shouldered' mean?

Tags: meaning

for example a quote from the haunted house: a high-shouldered young fellow.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest giving the entire sentence (or more) so that we have a better context.

I think, possibly, that "high-shouldered" may mean someone who stands tall out of pride, arrogance, or genuine self confidence. But with only "a high-shouldered young fellow" to go on, it's difficult, since it is a rather uncommon gorup of words to use in reference to people.

Answer (score 0):

The usage refers to the broad and high neck of a body-building power athlete with a prototypical **V** body shape.

Comment: I don't think that's quite right. There are two citations in OED for *high-shouldered* - in one the target being described is *tall, thin*, in the other *little, vulgar*. Neither are at all suggestive of an *athletic* physique. OED simply gives those usage instances without further clarification, but I'd guess it's more a reference to the kind of "stiff, haughty bearing" that might be associated with a [high-shouldered bow](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22high-shouldered+bow%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) (very formal - keeping the upper torso straight, and bending from the waist).

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't currently mean anything particular in the English language. A common phrase is *broad* shouldered which refers to an athletic build common among professional sports such as American football or boxing:

> [broad-shouldered](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/broad-shouldered) — having broad shoulders; "big-shouldered and heavy-armed"

It seems likely that "high-shouldered" means something similar but the only way to know is to ask the author or writer who used the phrase what they meant.

Other potentially relevant idioms:

- [chip on your shoulder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chip_on_shoulder) — holding a grudge or grievance that readily provokes disputation.
- [highbrow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highbrow) — elite, and generally carries a connotation of high culture.